# Render some View into string and send it through Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, render

I need render some **View** into string and send it through Json. 
Example.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetTreeUnit(string id)
        {
            int _id = id.ExtractID();
            string render ="";

            // render = GetStringView("SomeView");

            return Json(new { data = render });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created solution for my question. It's Extension that render view into string.

```
public static class RenderPartialToStringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// render PartialView and return string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="partialViewName"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, object model)
    {
        return RenderPartialToStringMethod(context, partialViewName, model);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// render PartialView and return string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="partialViewName"></param>
    /// <param name="viewData"></param>
    /// <param name="tempData"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RenderPartialToString(ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        return RenderPartialToStringMethod(context, partialViewName, viewData, tempData);
    }

    public static string RenderPartialToStringMethod(ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, partialViewName);

        if (result.View != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter output = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, result.View, viewData, tempData, output);
                    result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public static string RenderPartialToStringMethod(ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, object model)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
        TempDataDictionary tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
        return RenderPartialToStringMethod(context, partialViewName, viewData, tempData);
    }
}
```

And than we can render view in Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTreeUnit(string id)
{
    int _id = id.ExtractID();
    string render = ControllerContext.RenderPartialToString("SomeView");
    return Json(new { data = render });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a data that has been rendered by a view, change the controller to return a partial view.  This post is relevant: [asp.net MVC partial view controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371031/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-controller-action)

Answer (score -2):

The rendered string is DOM object, so just append it to HMTL element you want

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Controller\GetTreeUnit"
    data: "id=3",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        $("#content").append(result);
    }

});

<div id="content">
</div>
```