# Asp.Net MVC Partial View Update with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an asp.net mvc application. I need to reload a partial with ajax post. Here is my cshtml code inside main view:

```
<button data-url='@Url.Action("GetErrors", "Interface", new { servers = "S97EGESRV01" })'
            class="js-reload-details">
        Reload
    </button>
    <div id="errorListDiv">

        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/_ErrorListPartial.cshtml", Model.Errors)
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.js-reload-details').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var errorListDiv = $('#errorListDiv');
    var url = $(this).data("Interface/GetErrors?servers=S97EGESRV01");

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        errorListDiv.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

C#:

```
public ActionResult HatalariGetir(string servers= "All", InterfaceViewModel interfaceModel = null)
{
if (interfaceModel == null) {
     interfaceModel = new InterfaceViewModel();
}
// Some database processes
List<ErrorViewModel> modelList = new List<ErrorViewModel>();
// Populating modelList
interfaceModel.Errors = modelList;
return View("~/Views/Partials/_ErrorListPartial.cshtml", interfaceModel.Errors);
}
```

But the thing is when I click "Reload" button, whole page is loaded inside errorListDiv. Not just partial view. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_ErrorListPartial.cshtml", interfaceModel.Errors);
```

Unfortunately result is same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net MVC partial view controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371031/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-controller-action)

Comment: Why do you have to pass the path to the view?

Comment: Actually I don't have to. But otherwise result is same.

Comment: In your view put {Layout = null;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your view file.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your partial view is not working like **partial view**, it is rendering with **master layout** as a full view, so what you need is to explicitly tell in view that do not use any master layout by adding this line in top of view:

```
@{


Layout = null;

}
```