# return Views by PartialView method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> I want use ajax to prevent refresh my pages and for this I want return
>   **Views** by **PartialView** method from **controller** on ajax call.

The questions is:

1. Is it good way to return a `View` as `PartialView`?
2. How should I set path of views in `PartialView` method in `Controller`?

For example for _Index view in **Views/BasicInfo/_Index** path, I try 
        `PartialView("~/Views/BasicInfo/_Index");` ,
`PartialView("~/Views/BasicInfo/_Index.chtml");` , `PartialView("BasicInfo/_Index");`
, and get error as not found the view

**EDIT**

How specified view name into PartialView method, if view is in a folder out of the Shared folder and out of related view folder. For example My controller is name is **controller1** and my View is in this path **Views/BasicInfo/_Index** ?

Comment: What is your controller name? BasicInfoController?

Comment: yes, but is it matter? My be I call **PartialView** from other controller

Comment: I don't inderstand why you don't want to try to do the way I answered you earlier but it's up to you. You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371031/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-controller-action), I hope this will help you

Comment: **I want use ajax to prevent refresh my pages** please explain what you mean. Or explain another way what you want to accomplish...

Comment: @ Dave Alperovich: I want by clicking on menu, instead of refreshing whole page, I update only a section in my master layout with related view(not partial view). Now the problem is here that if I put views in **Shared** folder it's OK. But in other folder I couldn't set path (I don't know what should I write as path) in **PrtialView** methos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no limitation and it's not consider bad practice.
2. You have a typo at the `PartialView("~/Views/BasicInfo/_Index.chtml")` part of your question.

   You should write `return PartialView("~/Views/BasicInfo/_Index.cshtml")`

Comment: I wrote this path but it return error that couldn't find the **_index** view

Comment: Does the file exists? If it exists then it should have worked, what is the file's name? What is the full directory?

Comment: I wrote it in on quetsuion: **Views/BasicInfo/_Index**

Comment: Does it have any extension? The physical file is named _index with no extension?

Comment: I had a wrong on my file extension! You was right...Thanks man

Answer (score 6):

You should have this

- MyController

  - ActionResult -> Index
  - ActionResult -> IndexPartial
- Views

  - My

    - Index.cshtml (View)
    - IndexPartial.cshtml (PartialView)

Where:

Index.cshtml as complete view will have rendered the partial view with passed model (why so? to prevent code duplication)

```
@model YourModelType
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("IndexPartial", Model)
```

IndexPartial.cshtml is the partial view, something like

```
@model YourModelType

<h2>Some Title</h2>
 <div>
<h4>YourModel</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Property1)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Property1)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Property2)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Property2)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Now when you want the full View use MyController/Index and when you want Partial View instead you can get it with MyController/IndexPartial

Or you can use parameter on you action to specify the output:

```
public ActionResult GetMyView(bool? partial)
        {
           var model  = something;
           if (partial != null && partial)
             { 
                return PartialView("MyViewPartial", model)
             }

            return View("MyView", model);
        }
```

call for partial = yourHost/controller/GetMyView?partial=true

Now back to your question, yes you can return Partial View as View and vice versa. But you will face problems in appended html to pages via ajax (incomplete or overloaded html).

Comment: What's view name if I return **PartialView("ViewName", model);** from other controller?

Comment: Returning different partial view  return PartialView("controller/MyViewPartial", model ); but you use current controller. Or redirect to different controller return RedirectToAction("MyController", "GetMyView", model); but if you are and the best approach for post requests is this: return new GetMyView().GetMyView(model);

Answer (score 5):

you can use :

```
public PartialViewResult ActionMethodName() 
{
      return PartialView("_Index.chtml");
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult ActionMethodName() 
{
      return PartialView("_Index.chtml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea. .  Its a best practices to return as Partial View without page load.

```
 return PartialView("YourPartialView", model)
```

or else you can use absolute path

```
return  PartialView("~/Views/AnotherFolder/YourPartialView", model)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood by your question :
you have a controller name Controller1 which has ActionResult someMethod() and another controller BasicInfo which has a PartialView BasicInfo_Index and you want to return BasicInfo_Index partial view from someMethod():

One you can use the following code in someMethod() to get the partialview of BasicInfo controller :

```
var DesirePartialView = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "BasicInfo_Index");
        return PartialView(DesirePartialView.View);
```

Or You can use RedirectToAction() to redircet to action method in BasicInfo controller which returns the specified partialview

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of the method you're calling in the controller from ajax? It should be something like:

```
public PartialViewResult LoadPartialView() 
{
      return PartialView("~/Views/BasicInfo/_Index.chtml");
}
```