# Passing List of Model in Form Submission, Each Generated by HTML Partial View to a Controller Action ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to pass list of models, each generated by `HTML` `Partial View` to a `Controller Action` in `ASP.Net MVC 5`?

So I have a `View` (with a model called `WordModel`) where I call a `HTML partial View` (with a model called `MeaningModel`) multiple times in a form like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Entry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm" })) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <!--some other things here-->

  @Html.Partial("_Meaning", new MeaningModel() { Number = 1 })
  @Html.Partial("_Meaning", new MeaningModel() { Number = 2 })
  @Html.Partial("_Meaning", new MeaningModel() { Number = 3 })

  <!--some other things here-->

}
```

And the `MeaningModel` consists of multiple basic elements like the following:

```
public class MeaningModel {
    public string MeaningValue { get; set; }
    public int HomonimNumber { get; set; }
    public string Example1 { get; set; }
    public string Example2 { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

Now, in my `Controller`, I have an `Action` which handles the `Create` form submission:

```
// POST: Meaning/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(WordModel model, List<MeaningModel> meanings, FormCollection collection) {
    try {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } catch {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I could get the values I put in the main `View` in the `WordModel model`, but not the values in the `Partial Views` which consists of elements forming the `List<MeaningModel> meanings`. Is there any way to access them?

I could give each element in the `MeaningModel` different name per meaning model (such as `MeaningValue_1`, `MeaningValue_2`, `MeaningValue_3`, `HomonimNumber_1`, `HomonimNumber_2`, `HomonimNumber_3`, and so on) so that they will be captured by the `FormCollection`. But, as much as possible, I want to take advantage of the `MeaningModel` I have created and get them by the model.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Short answer is no (unless you were to pass a value for the `HtmlFieldPrefix` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808573/getting-the-values-from-a-nested-complex-object-that-is-passed-to-a-partial-view/29809907#29809907) which in your case would need to be `[#]` where `#` is a zero based indexer). Its far better to use a `for` loop of custom `EditorTemplate` so that you form controls are correctly named (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))

Comment: I look at your answer in the referred post. Thanks, that looks promising. I will test it out.

Comment: As a side note, does `WordModel` contain a property that is `List<MeaningModel>`? If so, then the 2nd parameter of the method would not be required - the 'prefix' could be `Meanings[#]` assuming that property is named `Meanings`. But using an `EditorTemplate` is really the correct approach

Comment: Also, this seems like it might be related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023419/can-we-append-chunk-of-html-in-jquery-using-html-partial-helper-c-sharp-asp-n) in which case neither approach is likely to work if your also dynamically adding items. You would need something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ah yes, the `WordModel` contain a property that is `List<MeaningModel> Meanings` I deleted the 2nd parameter and add the prefix `Meanings[#]` and it worked like charm. I also dynamically adding the item, but having `Number` to indicate them. So far it is OK. Thanks! I really owe you, pal! ;)

Comment: You just need to ensure that the indexer starts at zero and is consecutive (which will be an issue if you also dynamically delete any items in the collection - it would post back non-consecutive indexers and binding would fail)

Comment: The adding and deleting of the element is controlled by input number up and down. Thus, it is done one by one - always at the end of the collection. If this is not safe enough, I plan to change it to two buttons (+ and -). Not sure if they are good enough for the long run, but as of now, should be sufficient for my need - it is not the main problem now. The main problem is the collection passing which your answers greatly help to solve already. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121340/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ian).

Comment: @StephenMuecke That being said, I have a quick question, let say the `MeaningModel` is another complex model which have a `List<Example> Examples` property. Will the form be able to pass the `Examples` elements if we give name to the inputs with the naming convention `Meanings[#].Examples[#].SomeProperty` too?

Comment: Yes, you can nest as many levels deep as you want. So long as the indexers start at zero and are consecutive, then the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind them correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke great, thanks! ;)